# React Native Tooltip with Icon and TouchableHighlight?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tooltip, jsx, touchablehighlight

I am working on a [Tooltip][1] the users can click for an explanation. it looks like this

```
<Tooltip popover={<Text>my explanation</Text>} backgroundColor={'rgb(255, 179, 16)'}>
   <Text>?</Text>
</Tooltip>
```

The problem with this is that the user needs to click on top of the exact text to work, I wanted to create something like an invisible box around it that the user can click anywhere inside of it to trigger it.

```
<TouchableHighlight>
   <View style={{height: 48, alignSelf: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#2196F3'}}>
     <Tooltip popover={<Text>my explanation</Text>} backgroundColor={'rgb(240, 179, 16)'}>
       <Text>?</Text>
     </Tooltip>
   </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

and also tried this

```
 <Tooltip popover={<Text>my explanation</Text>} backgroundColor={'rgb(240, 179, 16)'}>
     <Icon.Button name="help-circle"
         backgroundColor="##3b5998"
         borderColor="##3b5998"
         color="##3b5998">
     </Icon.Button>
 </Tooltip>
```

but none of these two works. anyone can advise on what's wrong with my code and how I can fix it.
also, any recommendation on how I should deal with text in the future when I need them to be clickable and I want to extend the clickable area to a larger area than just the text itself.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     <Tooltip popover={<Text>my explanation</Text>} backgroundColor={'rgb(240, 179, 16)'}>
      <View style={{ height: 48, alignSelf: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#2196F3' }}>
        <Text>?</Text>
      </View>
    </Tooltip>
```

Basically you have to wrap the element inside tooltip
Also look at [hitslop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#hitslop) property of View to increase touchable area of view , its an alternative to increase touchable area by height and padding

Comment: this actually worked great as far as making the touchable area bigger. is there a way to include an icon with it too?  the problem I am having now is that by adding the "?" it kind changed the layout and pushed my switch button to the middle of the screen, is there a way to keep everything the same and adding the "?" where I market with X without changing position of the switch? I added a picture to my original post for reference

Comment: I cannot see the picture you have attached to this post